# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'QN_WA' referenced before assignment Python 3.4

Tags: python

I can't proceed to my next task because of this error. I searched about the error already and did what others suggested but it doesn't work for my code. So I'm hoping that someone could help me about it. Here's my code:

```
if self.techskills == 11:
        c = con.execute("SELECT Centroid FROM Centroid WHERE ItemID = 25")
        TS_centroid = c.fetchone()[0]

        TS_AA = (min(a1, a2) * TS_centroid) + (pow(a3,2))
        TS_BB = (min(a1, a2) + a3)
        TS_WA = TS_AA/TS_BB

elif self.techskills == 12:
        c = con.execute("SELECT Centroid FROM Centroid WHERE ItemID = 24")
        TS_centroid = c.fetchone()[0]

        TS_AA = (min(a1, a2) * TS_centroid) + (pow(a3,2))
        TS_BB = (min(a1, a2) + a3)
        TS_WA = TS_AA/TS_BB
if self.qualityofwork == 11:
        c = con.execute("SELECT Centroid FROM Centroid WHERE ItemID = 25")
        QL_centroid = c.fetchone()[0]

        QL_AA = (min(a4, a5) * QL_centroid) + (pow(a6,2))
        QL_BB = (min(a4, a5) + a6)
        QL_WA = QL_AA/QL_BB

elif self.qualityofwork == 12:
        c = con.execute("SELECT Centroid FROM Centroid WHERE ItemID = 24")
        QL_centroid = c.fetchone()[0]

        QL_AA = (min(a4, a5) * QL_centroid) + (pow(a6,2))
        QL_BB = (min(a4, a5) + a6)
        QL_WA = QL_AA/QL_BB
 overall = (TS_WA + QL_WA)/2
    print(overall)
```

I just reduced the code to make it short. I got this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


    overall = (TS_WA + QL_WA)/2
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'QL_WA' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If either of your  statements don't evaluate to True, `QL_WA` never gets defined. You need to set a default value outside of the if checks or move the `overall = (TS_WA + QL_WA)/2` inside the body of the statement.

if `self.qualityofwork` is neither 11 or 12 then it never gets assigned, you can set a default value as I mentioned or use an else where you assign it a value there then assign `overall = (TS_WA + QL_WA)/2`.

If you expect `self.qualityofwork` to always be 11 or 12 then you have a bug somewhere in your previous code.

You can set it to `None`:

```
 QL_WA = None
 if self.techskills == 11:  
   .....
```

Then use `if QL_WA is not None:overall = (TS_WA + QL_WA)/2`.

Answer (score -1):

**UnboundLocalError** arises in three different conditions.
Condition 1;
As the previous post stated this code produces error.

```
'a' in globals()
False
def f():
  if False:
    a=1
  print a
f() # UnboundLocalError
```

By the time python has parsed the identifier 'a' in the above if block it had learned a name but the name referrs to no objects. So produces an error when accessed in runtime.

Condition 2; A modified version of the above.

```
a=0
'a' in globals()
True
def f():
  if False:
    a=1
  print a
f() # UnboundLocalError
```

If we want to make 'a' local when the 'if' condition is true and otherwise not, it can be coded as below;

```
if 'a' not in locals():
  global a
print a
```

Condition 3; Python 3

```
'a' in globals()
False
def f1():
  a=1
  def f2():
    a += 1 # 'a' is non-local and non-global
  f2()
f1() # UnboundLocalError
```

here making 'a' `global a` triggers 'NameErro' because `'a' in globals()` was `False`. Making 'a' `nonlocal a` gives access to 'a' in 'f1'. 
Even if `'a' in globals()` were `True`, `nonlocal` refers only to the outer scope.

Comment: it is in a function so it would be an UnboundLocalError. global has nothing to do with it

Comment: `if` references `self` but you say it's in a function. Even if it were in a function never before assigned vars get NameError.

Comment: Assignment to a var, previously assigned in an outer scope, in an inner scope makes a var local to the scope. Accessing is just fine too, it gets the last assignment. **referenced before assignment** error means it's ambigous reference is made to local one ore not.

Comment: @padraic-cunningham Thanks for clarification. Great! But see the official docs never say about this. By the way, should I delete my post?

Comment: No worries, that is up to yourself really.